# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getSystemServiceName(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Java and recently I am having this error when trying to access one method of a class to another class

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getSystemServiceName(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference

at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemServiceName(ContextWrapper.java:819)
                                                                                                        at android.content.Context.getSystemService
```

I have this main class `EmersysPluginPlugin`

```
@CapacitorPlugin(name = "EmersysPlugin")
public class EmersysPluginPlugin extends Plugin {
    PushNotificationService pushNotificationService = new PushNotificationService();

    @Override
    public void load() {
        ...

        //Calling other class' method to initiate the notification channel
        pushNotificationService.createNotificationChannel();
    }
}
```

and here is the `PushNotificationService` class

```
public class PushNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
      ....
    }

    public void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           
            CharSequence name = "Test";
            String description = "Test Test";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
           
           //THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE
           //THE NotificationManager.class IS EMPTY OBJECT
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Log.d("CreateNotChannel ", "Notiiftcain channel initialized");
        }
    }
}
```

seems like I need to initialize this `NotificationManager.class`, but not really sure how ..
Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think the `context` is not ready (i.e., equals to `null`) so you can't use it. Beaware the life cycle of a service. The `context` is ready to be used when `Service#onCreate` is called.

Comment: Why I mention `context` here becoz you are calling `this.getSystemService`. `this` equals to `FirebaseMessagingService` which is extended from `Service` > `ContextWrapper` > `Context`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to the `ContextWrapper` class. You need to use context.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, I aget another error ``` java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{io.ionic.starter/io.ionic.starter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference```